# Ubuntu installer and grub don't see Windows installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair, nvme

On a system with nvme memory, I installed (K)ubuntu 19.04. The installer did not detect the preinstalled Windows 10 installation and only offered a complete wipe. So I prepared the disk with `parted` and did a manual install.

```
Disklabel type: gpt

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1026048   1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1288192 283981890 282693699 134,8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 283983872 285702143   1718272   839M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 285702144 498561023 212858880 101,5G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p6 498561024 500117503   1556480   760M Linux swap
```

However, `update-grub` can't detect the windows installation (even when the windows partition is mounted) and I can't boot into Windows any more.

I've tried `boot-repair` with different options, but no avail.
Here is my updated bootinfo generated by boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VrZ5N9VTvq/

Questions:

1. Why is Windows not in the GRUB menu?
2. How can I revive Windows 10?
3. How come the installer doesn't offer the "install alongside windows" option?
4. Why is `boot-repair` failing? Can it handle nvme media? Is it outdated?

It doesn't seem these questions are answered in [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: @EODCraftStaff you are saying it is a UEFI issue?

Comment: You can only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. You now have two.  Remove p5 or at least remove boot, esp flags. Then reinstall grub. For grub to see Windows you need to also turn off fast start up/hibernation in Windows. See lines starting at line 64. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions